# Use TFS 2010 for VS2005 version control w/o TS2005?

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2005

My team is moving to TFS 2010, but all of our old projects are from our stand alone VS 2005 and VS 2008.  We did not have Team Server.  Can put our projects under source control in TFS 2010 without upgrading and migrating them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your VS 2005/2008 projects upgraded (most likely VS 2010 will only touch the solution file), then you can install

this for VS 2005 (allows you to connect to TFS 2010 from VS 2005)
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/979258?p=1

this for VS 2008
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=cf13ea45-d17b-4edc-8e6c-6c5b208ec54d

Comment: This is a partial solution.  A thorough explanation of the entire process may be found at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/85602e42-9c99-424c-9ed9-cebe883a847b

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to migrate them using `VSSConverter`.  Another option is to simply keep the old VSS2005 in play and switch Source Control as necessary in VS.